# f# adding non interface functions to object expressions

Tags: f#

Say I have an interface `ICache` which defines two functions, `Function1` and `Function2` and I use an object expression to implement it, but I also want to add a helper function:

```
let WebCache =
    {    new ICache with
         member __.HelperFunction = //this doesn't work!
         member __.Function1 = foo
         member __.Function2 = bar
    }
```

F# seems to not allow you to add any methods that are not part of the interface.   Is there a workaround? If I want to do this, should I not be using an object expression in the first place?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define the helper function as an ordinary (local) function outside of the object expression:

```
let WebCache =
    let helper n = 
         printfn "Helping %" n
    { new ICache with
         member __.Function1 = helper 1
         member __.Function2 = helper 2 }
```

Comment: Aha, so simple! Thank you.